# JQuery Full Calendar Event click run MySQL select query using event id

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

Hi I have been looking at JQuery Full Calendar Every thing is work great but does anyone know how to run a Mysql select query using the event id. What i am trying to achieve is on the  event click, take the event id and run a MySQL select query and then open the results in a bootstrap modal.

custom.js
event click:

```
        eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                 endtime = moment(event.end).format('h:mm:ss a');
        starttime = moment(event.start).format('Do MMM YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    startit =  moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    endit =  moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                  $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
            $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
              $('#appointment #when').text(mywhen);
            $('#appointment').modal();
      $.ajax({
    url: '',
    data: {'id':event.id, 'staff':event.resources},
    type: "POST",
    success: function (json) {
        alert('Added Successfully');
    }
});
          console.log(startit);
          console.log(event);
          console.log(event.resources);

        },
```

The Modal index.php

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="appointment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Appointment</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div id="modalTitle"></div></div><div class="col-md-8">
  <div id="when">
  </div>
</div>  
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

mysql select query index.php

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT AppId, CustomerId, CONCAT(Clients.FirstName,' ',Clients.LastName) AS name, Staff, TimeStart, StageTime, GapTime, StageTime2, GapTime2, StageTime3, 
Services.Service, Services.Background, Services.ServiceCost, Services.Oap, Cost FROM Appointments
LEFT JOIN Apptime ON Appointments.AppId = Apptime.AppT 
LEFT JOIN Apptime2 ON Appointments.AppId = Apptime2.AppT2 
LEFT JOIN Apptime3 ON Appointments.AppId = Apptime3.AppT3
LEFT JOIN Clients ON Appointments.CustomerId = ClientId
LEFT JOIN Services ON Appointments.ServiceId = SId 
            WHERE
                AppId =".$Id;

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('-1'.mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  {result ....} }?>
```

I can get the event id and make the modal open. I have tried to post  to self using ajax. I need the information to populate the modal because i have a 3 part appointment  eg. 30min then gap 60min the second part of the appointment 30 min. and i need to chance the lengths.. of appointments. So in a nut shell click event triggers MySQL query with event id the bootstrap modal open with the result. Anyone any ideas please